# Vue component inside another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, compiler-errors, vue-component

Quick question about vue components. So can i do this?

App.vue file > import test.vue component in app.vue> import test2.vue component in test.vue

I get a `Failed to compile error`. Thanks.

**app.vue:**

```js
import test from './components/test.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    'app-test': test,
  }
}
```

**test.vue:**

```js
import test2 from './components/test2.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    'app-test2': test2,
  }
}
```

Comment: do you get anything else with that error? 1. test.vue and test2.vue are on the same folder by what i see... so you should access them like `import test2 from './test2.vue';` 2. i think you might be creating a circular reference... you don't seem to be doing `app -> test -> test2`  but `test <--> test2`

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```js
import test2 from './components/test2.vue';
```

by

```js
import test2 from 'test2.vue';
```

or

```js
import test2 from './test2.vue';
```

Answer (score 0):

try without ";" I'm not use that, so it could works

`import test2 from './components/test2.vue'`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is the one below if both components are in the same level directory:

```js
import test2 from "components/test2.vue";
```